# Enabling Annotation Processing and Intellij Lombok

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-plugin

I am using Intellij 2019.1. I have a lombok dependancy in my application. I have enabled annotation processing in IntelliJ Preferences. I still get a compilation error for all the Lombok Annotations. Can one of you help me in resolving this error?

Comment: Have you installed lombok plugin? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Comment: did you install plugin ? File -->Setting -->plugin -->lombok . do install and restart it should be fine